# Get Element using XPath in Puppeteer

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, puppeteer

I am trying to scrape multiple elements with the same class names but each has a different number of children. I am looking for a way to select specific elements using the xpath(this would make it easiest for my loop).

```
const gameTimeElement = await page.$$('//*[@id="section-content"]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div['+ i + ']');
const gameTimeString = await gameTimeElement[j].$eval('h3', (h3) => h3.innerHTML);
```

This currently does not work.
After I select the element, I grab the h3 tag inside and evaluate it to get the innerHTML.
Is there a way to do this utilizing xpath?

```
<div id="section-content" style="display: block;">
</div>
<div class="matches">
        <div class="day day-28-1" data-week="1" style="display: block;">
            <h4>Sat, March 28, 2020</h4>
            <div class="day-wrap">
                <div class="match region-7-57d5ab4-9qs98v" data-week="1">
                    <h3 class="time">2:00PM 
                        <span>(Central Daylight Time)</span>
                        <span class="fr">Best of 7</span>
                    </h3>
                    <div class="row ac ">
                        <div class="col-xs-3 ar">
                            <img class="team-logo" src="url"></div>
                            <div class="col-xs-2 al">
                                <h4 class="loss">(NA)<br>
                                    <span class="team-name">Team1</span>
                                    <br>
                                    <span class="win spoiler-wrap">0</span>
                                </h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-2">
                                <img class="league-logo" src="url">
                                <h4> V.S.</h4>
                            </div> 
                            <div class="col-xs-2 ar">
                                <h4 class="">(NA)<br>
                                    <span class="team-name">Team2</span>
                                    <br>
                                    <span class="win spoiler-wrap">4</span>
                                </h4>
                            </div>
```

This is a sample of what I am working with for HTML on the website.

Comment: It should be possible with XPath. Please provide a sample of data and tell us the specific elements you're looking for. It's hard to work blindfolded.

Comment: I went ahead and updated the question to provided more information.

Comment: OK. Post is below. Hope I fully understand your request.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `div class="day-wrap"` could have a different number of childs. But I don't think that's a problem.

You want to get game times of all Rocket League matches. As you've noticed, games times are located within h3 elements. You can access it directly with one of the following XPaths :

```
//div[@id="section-content"]//h3
//div[@class="day-wrap"]//h3
//div[contains(@class,"match region")]//h3
```

If you want something for a loop then you can try :

```
(//div[@class="day-wrap"]//h3)[i]
```

where i is the number to increment (from 1 to x).

Side notes : your sample data looks incorrect (according to your XPath). You have a closing `div` line 2 and it seems you omit `div class="row middle-xs center-xs weeks"` before `div class="matches"`.